# Manifest merger failed with multiple errors after adding material design support

Tags: android, manifest

My application was working fine before but recently after android pie update I have changed the targetSDKVersion to 28 and added material design support and got this error.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91      is also present at
>   [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).       Suggestion: add
>   'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element
>   at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-53:19 to override.

I have updated all the libraries and tried all the suggestions that it gave me but still, I cannot figure out the program. Below are the dependencies that I have added.

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0"
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation group: 'com.android.support', name: 'customtabs', version: '28.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Update your question with complete gradle code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it says your `support` dependency has conflict with `androidx.core` dependency

the android studio cannot use `android x` dependencies with previous `support` dependencies at the same time. you should just use one of them.

use these dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
```

use this link to refactor your dependencies
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor

Comment: I had already added the material dependency and after your answer, I added the androidx dependency but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: you should remove other dependencies.
take a screenshot from your gradle file

Comment: I have added them in my question.

Comment: remove support dependencies
then add each dependency from android x 
like 
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

Comment: I'm getting the same error even after migrating to androidx.

Answer (score 0):

My error is solved and my assumption is that in order to use material design, we need to update the android studio to 3.2 because before I was using 3.1 and migrated my project to androidx. And add these two lines

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

in the gradle.properties file of the project or else you will get the error mentioned in my question.

I tried without it and found that it was because of it that I was getting the error. To upgrade the dependencies to androidx visit this site -  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/refactor or you can do it automatically from the refractor tab of the studio.