# Menifest Merge error like most hedek probelm

Tags: android, android-studio

ERROR: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
    is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:10:5-40:19 to override.

how to solve these error

Comment: What are your dependencies?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/54167109/115145 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/51742697/115145 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/52566815/115145.

Comment: @axar. This has already been answered. You can try this to troubleshoot similar manifest merge issue in the future. https://stackoverflow.com/a/56784046/4377954

Comment: i am not use any knid of butterknife and material and firebase libraruy but still give me error

Comment: http://prntscr.com/oangt8